# Keep <p:dialog> open when validation has failed

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a CRUD page which shows data from a query (a List of domain objects) in a Primefaces datatable.

```
<p:dataTable 
                id="negozi" 
                var="n" 
                value="#{nController.theListFromQuery}" 
                rowKey="#{n.id}"
                selection="#{nController.selected}" 
                selectionMode="single">

                <p:column headerText="Field1">
                    <h:outputText value="#{n.f1}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Field2">
                    <h:outputText value="#{n.f2}" />
                </p:column>
<p:column style="width:4%">
                    <p:commandButton 
                        actionListener="#{nController.prepareEdit(n)}"
                        update=":editDialogId" 
                        oncomplete="editDialog.show()" 
                        value="Edit" />
                </p:column>
...
```

By clicking on the edit button a dialog will be shown:

```
    <p:dialog 
                header="Edit N" 
                widgetVar="editDialog" 
                id="editDialogId">

                    <h:form id="formDialog">

                        <h:panelGrid id="editDialogTable" columns="2" cellpadding="10" style="margin:0 auto;">

                            <p:outputLabel for="field1" value="F1:" />
                            <p:inputText id="field1" value="#{nController.selected.f1}" />
                            <p:outputLabel for="field2" value="F2:" />
                            <p:inputText id="field2" value="#{nController.selected.f2}" />
<p:commandButton 
                        value="Confirm" 
                        actionListener="#{nController.doEdit}" 
                        update=":form" 
                        oncomplete="editDialog.hide()"
                        rendered="#{nController.selected.id!=null}" />                  
...
```

It works. Now I want to make F1 a required field.

I add the "required" attribute to the inputText field and what happens?

When I try to confirm the form without the required field, the entity is not edited (that's right) but the dialog is closed (that's NOT right!)

When I reopen the dialog I can see the red highlight on the required (and invalid) field.

**What I want is to prevent the dialog closing if the form is invalid.**

Do I have to write some JS or will JSF help me?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The PrimeFaces ajax response puts an `args` object in the scope which has a `validationFailed` property. You could just make use of it.

```
oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('editDialog').hide()"
```

*(the `args` precheck is necessary to not cause a JS error when an exception is thrown during request)*

You could refactor it to a reusable JS function as follows.

```
oncomplete="hideDialogOnSuccess(args, 'editDialog')"
```

```
function hideDialogOnSuccess(args, dialogWidgetVar) {
    if (args && !args.validationFailed) {
        PF(dialogWidgetVar).hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

this post is now three years old, but I have found helpful, so my findings may help others.

In PF 5.x at least, it seems that the solution provided by BalusC has to be modified in two ways. (1) add the "args" argument to the call in oncomplete event hander, and (2) use the PF primefaces primitive to identify the widget in PF tables. Here is the code I am using:

```
oncomplete="hideDialogOnSuccess(args, PF('editDialog'))"

function hideDialogOnSuccess(args, dialogWidgetVar) {
    if (args && !args.validationFailed) {
        dialogWidgetVar.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't gain much reputation, but you can, suggest edits to the good accepted answer. Instead you gain 'real world' reputation and appreciation then ;-) never the less…  both upvoted

Comment: BalusC has updated his answer, so mine is now irrelevant. See his.

Comment: he already did before I commented here (looking at the timestamp) Sorry... Thanks anyway for finding out and sharing

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the cleanest solution.
Doing this you **don't need to change your buttons code**.
This solution overrides the hide function prototype.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.prototype.originalHide = PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.prototype.hide; // keep a reference to the original hide()
    PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.prototype.hide = function() {
        var ajaxResponseArgs = arguments.callee.caller.arguments[2]; // accesses oncomplete arguments
        if (ajaxResponseArgs && ajaxResponseArgs.validationFailed) {
            return;  // on validation error, prevent closing
        }
        this.originalHide();
    };
});
```

This way, you can keep your code like:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" oncomplete="videoDetalheDialogJS.hide();" 
   actionListener="#{videoBean.saveVideo(video)}" />
```

Comment: How is this "the cleanest"? You're recommending an 11-line function over an option to simply add a variable check that's readily available?

Comment: well.. I see you point.. but the thing here is to do a "transparent hide"; I mean... you always do a regular hide() regardless of it's validated or not (rather than testing sometimes); you ask to hide everywhere like: oncomplete="editDialog.hide()" and don't care if validation will fail or not; it will be handled "below"...

Answer (score 0):

to keep the dialog Open on validation Failed, you just need set the commandButton as follows:

```
<p:commandButton value="save"
action="#{YourBean.yourActionMethod}"
oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('yourDialogWidgetVar').hide()"/>
```

I gonna leave here a complete example:

```
<h:form id="ad-form">
            <p:dialog id="ad-dialog" widgetVar="adDialog" modal="true" width="400"
            closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false" header="Addreass">

            <p:messages id="a-msgs" closable="true" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="ad-painel-dialog" width="100%">
                <p:outputLabel value="Country" for="country" />
                <p:inputText id="country" style="width:100%"
                    value="#{clientSaverBean.editableAddress.country}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="City" for="city" />
                <p:inputText id="city"
                    value="#{clientSaverBean.editableAddress.city}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Zip-Code" for="zipcode" />
                <p:inputText id="zipcode"
                    value="#{clientSaverBean.editableAddress.zipCode}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Street" for="street" />
                <p:inputTextarea id="street"
                    value="#{clientSaverBean.editableAddress.street}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Number" for="number" />
                <p:inputText id="number"
                    value="#{clientSaverBean.editableAddress.number}" />

                <h:panelGroup />

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="save"
                        action="#{clientSaverBean.saveAddress}"
                        process=":ad-form:ad-dialog"
                        update=":ad-form:a-msgs :ad-form:ad-painel-dialog :client-form:ad-table" 
                        oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('adDialog').hide()"/>
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
```