# How to stay in the dialog if OK button `action` reports error?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am looking for a way to properly handle pop-up dialog close events.

I have OK and Cancel buttons. When OK is selected, `actionListener` and `action` are executed. Depending on the result of `action`, I would like to either:

1. Close the dialog.
2. Stay in the dialog and display error or warning message.

Currently I can only do the 1st case with this code:

```
<p:commandButton 
    id="btnOkId" 
    value="OK" 
    ajax="true" 
    type="submit" 
    actionListener="#{WatchfolderEditBean.save}" 
    action="#WatchfolderMgmtBean.refreshList}" 
    oncomplete="dlgEditWF.hide();" 
    update=":wfMgtForm:wfTable :editWFForm:messagesId"/>
```

What is the proper way of doing it to be able to stay in the dialog in case `action` reports some kind of error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep <p:dialog> open when validation has failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328115/keep-pdialog-open-when-validation-has-failed) and [Keep p:dialog up when a validation error occurs after submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-up-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit)

Comment: yes, please close as duplicate.