# Update datatable from dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have datatable with button "add new". 
Desired scenario is:

- Click on the button
- Fill in the form which is dispalyed in the dialog
- When validation fails show validation messages in the dialog When
- validation pass close the dialog, show success message and update
  table

With current setup 2 thing dont work

- Updating the datatable
- Validation messages are also displayed above the datatable, not onlu
  in the dialog (in the place for all messages - thats ok) but after
  successfull save, these messages stays there

Messages displaying on top of the page

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" escape="false"/>
```

My XHTML:

```
<h:form id="lookupTableForm">
        <p:dataTable
                id="lookupTable"
                widgetVar="lookupTable"
                var="lookup"
                value="#{qlookupListBean.lookups}"
                styleClass="listBlock"
                lazy="true"
                rows="20"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                sortBy="#{lookup.name}"
                sortOrder="ascending"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="20,100,500">

            <f:facet name="header">#{msg['integrations.tabs.qlookup.title']}</f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['qloookup.name']}"
                    sortBy="#{lookup.name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{lookup.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['qloookup.type.in']}"
                      sortBy="#{lookup.typeIn}">
                <h:outputText value="#{lookup.typeIn}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['qloookup.value.in']}"
                      sortBy="#{lookup.valueIn}">
                <h:outputText value="#{lookup.valueIn}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['qloookup.type.out']}"
                      sortBy="#{lookup.typeOut}">
                <h:outputText value="#{lookup.typeOut}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['qloookup.value.out']}"
                      sortBy="#{lookup.valueOut}">
                <h:outputText value="#{lookup.valueOut}" />
            </p:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <div class="reset"></div>
                <p:commandButton
                        onclick="newDialog.show()"
                        value="#{msg['qloookup.table.button.new']}"
                        styleClass="primaryButton" />
            </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog
            id="newDialog"
            header="#{msg['qloookup.new.title']}"
            closable="true"
            modal="true"
            position="top"
            resizable="false"
            width="430"
            height="400"
            onShow="finFwUI.setDialogPosition()"
            widgetVar="newDialog" styleClass="passwordDialog">

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="w30">
                <p:outputLabel for="name"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.new.name']}" />
                <p:inputText id="name"
                        value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.name}"
                        required="true"
                        styleClass="w30">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="35" />
                </p:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="name" display="text" />
                <p:outputLabel for="inType"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.type.in']}" />
                <p:selectOneMenu
                        id="inType"
                        value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.typeIn}"
                        required="true"
                        filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="contains"
                        styleClass="w30">
                    <f:selectItems
                            value="#{qlookupListBean.qualifierTypes}"
                            var="type"
                            itemLabel="#{type.type}"
                            itemValue="#{type.type}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                            listener="#{qlookupListBean.reloadInValues}"
                            update="inValues" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="inType" display="text" />
                <p:outputLabel for="inValues"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.type.in']}" />
                <p:selectOneMenu
                        id="inValues"
                        value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.valueIn}"
                        required="true"
                        filter="#{qlookupListBean.inValues.size() gt 8}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains"
                        styleClass="w30">
                    <f:selectItems
                            value="#{qlookupListBean.inValues}"
                            var="type"
                            itemLabel="#{type.value}"
                            itemValue="#{type.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="inValues" display="text" />
                <p:outputLabel for="key"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.key']}" />
                <p:inputText id="key"
                             value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.key}"
                             required="true"
                             styleClass="w30">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="35" />
                </p:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="key" display="text" />
                <p:outputLabel for="outType"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.type.out']}" />
                <p:selectOneMenu
                        id="outType"
                        value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.typeOut}"
                        required="true"
                        filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="contains"
                        styleClass="w30">
                    <f:selectItems
                            value="#{qlookupListBean.qualifierTypes}"
                            var="type"
                            itemLabel="#{type.type}"
                            itemValue="#{type.type}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                            listener="#{qlookupListBean.reloadOutValues}"
                            update="outValues" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="outType" display="text" />
                <p:outputLabel for="outValues"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.value.out']}" />
                <p:selectOneMenu
                        id="outValues"
                        value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.valueOut}"
                        required="true"
                        filter="#{qlookupListBean.outValues.size() gt 8}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains"
                        styleClass="w30">
                    <f:selectItems
                            value="#{qlookupListBean.outValues}"
                            var="type"
                            itemLabel="#{type.value}"
                            itemValue="#{type.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="outValues" display="text" />
                <p:outputLabel for="value"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.value']}" />
                <p:inputText id="value"
                             value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.value}"
                             required="true"
                             styleClass="w30">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="70" />
                </p:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="value" display="text" />
                <p:outputLabel for="description"
                               value="#{msg['qloookup.description']}" />
                <p:inputTextarea id="description"
                                 value="#{qlookupListBean.lookup.description}"
                                 styleClass="w30">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="255" />
                </p:inputTextarea>
                <h:outputText value="" />
                <p:message for="description" display="text" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <div class="buttonsBlock">
                <p:commandButton
                        styleClass="primaryButton"
                        value="#{msg['button.save']}"
                        update="@form"
                        action="#{qlookupListBean.save}"
                        oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) { newDialog.hide(); updateTable(); }" /><!--    see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9195852/204950   -->
                <p:commandButton
                        value="#{msg['button.cancel']}"
                        styleClass="buttonRight"
                        onclick="newDialog.hide();"
                        immediate="true" />
                <p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="@(lookupTableForm:lookupTable)" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

What should i change to get it work? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Resolved the messages issue by modifying update on save command button

```
<p:commandButton
                        styleClass="primaryButton"
                        value="#{msg['button.save']}"
                        update="@form, @(:messages)"
                        action="#{qlookupListBean.save}"
                        oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) { newDialog.hide(); updateTable(); }" />
```

**EDIT 2**
I was wrong. Validation messages disapears with previous but now when i click save on empty form. Non ajax POST request is send on the server, page is reloaded and dialog is not shown.

Comment: You're updating only the dialog's form. You have two choices: make both datatable and dialog share the same form OR keep it as it is and refer to the other form `update=":lookupTableForm"`.

Comment: Check firebug (or equivalent) for error messages, if there are any: post them. Try to remove the `@` from the `update=..` in the `remoteCommand`. Move the `p:messages` inside the dialog.

Comment: Thats why i am using remotecomand tag. If i have it in same form it sends new non-ajax-request for save button and i dont want that. 
When i add `update=":lookupTableForm"` i get unknown id error. Datatable id can be reached by @(lookupTableForm:lookupTable) but this starts to send non-ajax requests too.

Comment: What are you trying with `p:remoteCommand`? I think it's unecessary..

Comment: I am trying to update datatable after successfull save was done.

Comment: You could initiate the update proces from your `qlookupListBean` by using the `RequestContext.update` method. Then you dont need a `p:remoteCommand`.

Comment: Nice, i did not know about this, but unfortunately it causes my loader to block ui and never stops.
`<p:ajaxStatus id="ajaxStatusPanel">  
    <f:facet name="start">
     <div style="display: none" class="blockOverlay"></div>
     <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/preloader.gif" />  
    </f:facet>  
    <f:facet name="complete">  
     <h:outputText value="" />  
    </f:facet>  
   </p:ajaxStatus>  `

Comment: I resolved it by doing `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ajaxStatusPanel");` in bean. But then i am back to where i was, because datatable is not updated

Comment: I think i did it. I update the parent form with `RequestContext.update` and it updates datatable.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE instead of "Wall Of Code".