# popup disappear even when validation failed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, popup

I am working with primefaces 3.5 and jsf2.I have a command Button that shows up a dialog as a  popup to register a new customer. All fields are required. when i submit the form with missing some fields the popup disappears as if nothing happened. And when i click again on the button new it shows up the last filled form with error messages. 
I need this to be shown first time i submit when validation is failed.
Here is a short version of my html code

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
<p:panel id="datatablePanel">
.........
 <p:commandButton style="width: 8%;height: 100%"  id="newButton"  value="New" oncomplete="customerDialogNew.show()"  icon="ui-icon-star"/>  
</p:panel>
</:form>
<h:form id="newCustomerForm">
   <p:panel id="customerPannel">
        <p:dialog draggable="true"  header="New Customer" widgetVar="customerDialogNew" id="dialog2">            
           <p:panelGrid id="newCustomer" columns="6" > 
<p:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
<p:inputText id="name" value="#{customerMB.name}" title="Name" required="true" requiredMessage="The Name field is required."/>
<p:message for="name" />
......
<p:commandButton   style="height: 100%;width: 15%" value="Cancel" update="customerPannel" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n"  process="@this" oncomplete="customerDialogNew.show()" />  
<p:commandButton ajax="false" style="height: 100%;width: 15%" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="{customerMB.addCustomer()}"/>               
       </p:dialog>
     </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep p:dialog up when a validation error occurs after submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-up-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit)

Comment: See the link above for your question, it may be helpful for you. Apart from that and unrelated to the problem, I don't understand what your `Cancel` button does. In order of a `process="@this"` you should use an `immediate="true"` and hide the dialog instead of showing it I think.

Comment: I already tried the solution suggested in the above link but it didn't work for me. about the cancel button: if i use immediate="true" when i click on the cancel button the dialog disappear instead or resetting the fields filled.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Cancel Button：**
              Change `oncomplete="customerDialogNew.show()"` to
                     `oncomplete="customerDialogNew.hide()"`.
2. **Save Button：**
              Remove `ajax=false`.
              Add `update="newCustomer"`.

So your Buttons looks like:

```
<p:commandButton   style="height: 100%;width: 15%" value="Cancel" update="customerPannel" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n"  process="@this" oncomplete="customerDialogNew.hide()" />  
<p:commandButton style="height: 100%;width: 15%" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="#{customerMB.addCustomer()}"  update="newCustomer"/>
```

**Backing Bean：**

```
 public void addCustomer(){
    //do something
    System.out.println(name+"");

    //set name to null to prevent seeing old value when adding the second(or more) customer
    name=null;
    //Hide customerDialogNew if everything done.
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("customerDialogNew.hide()");
}
```