# Show dialog after successful operation in jsf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am adding some value to database in jsf. I have a manage bean for this purpose. Now when insertion is successful then I want to show a success alert dialog. please tell me how to do it?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-open-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit and be creative

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a dialog component in your page (the same page that calls your bean to insert a value into the DB for instance)

```
p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="widgetVarOfDialog"
```

Then let assume that you have either a `commandButton` or a `commandLink` (you don't provide enough information in your first post) that triggers the insert action in your bean. Just add an oncomplete callback:

```
p:commandButton action="#{bean.insertValue}" oncomplete="PF('widgetVarOfDialog').show()"
```

You could also display a `p:dialog` right from your bean method by using:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("PF('widgetVarOfDialog').show()");
```

Comment: Seems to me the dialog will be shown no matter if the insert was not succesful

Comment: Yeah but, as the original question is too vague, I provided a generic solution. Use the programmatic way to display the dialog based on the insert return status or  add a context parameter which can be processed in the oncomplete event.

Comment: Use parts from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-open-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit