# Execute p:ajax only if input is valid

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to show a primefaces overlay with search suggestions using `p:ajax` like following:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.input}" required="true" 
    validatorMessage="Add at least 3 characters">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="64"/>
    <p:ajax event="keyup" delay="200" process="@this" 
        listener="#{bean.createSuggestions()}"
        update="overlay"
        oncomplete="showOverlay()"/>
</p:inputText>
```

The problem is, that no validation takes place.

*I could use javascript onstart handler and check input again as a workaround.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Execute p:ajax only if input is valid*

That's only possible if you validate in client side, as you already figured for the workaround.

The alternative would be to execute `oncomplete` only when there's no validation error.

```
oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) showOverlay()"
```

The doublecheck and ugly XML escaping is necessary for reasons mentioned here: [Keep p:dialog open when a validation error occurs after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-up-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit/9195852#9195852).

Comment: You can also use a javascript callback from the listener.