# Primefaces schedule ignores required fields

Tags: primefaces

I'm setting up a web page with a schedule nearly identical to [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml) with the editable schedule. Both my setup and the editable schedule have the same flaw though: if you leave the required 'Titles' field blank and save the event, the Event Details dialog will still hide. If you try to make a new event, the previous dialog details will carry over and populate the new dialog. I'd like for my dialog to not hide until all required fields are populated. Suggestions?

Comment: 'nearly identical'... = different... Please read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and act accordingly. No-one is able to help you with a question that is formulated like this one

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-up-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit