# Updating p:dialog clears p:message which inside same dialog

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Am Upgrading application from PrimeFaces 6.1 to PrimeFaces 6.2. I have `<p:dialog appendTo="@(body)" id="dialog" widgetVar="widgetVar" modal="true">` with `<p:message id="validation">` element inside it.

Am opening dialog using `PF('widgetVar').show()`. When I click `p:commandButton` inside dialog, doing some validation and showing message using below code,

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("validation", new 
FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "validation error", null))
```

With in the same method am reopening dialog and update it with below code,

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.update("dialog");
context.execute("PF('widgetVar').show();")
```

In PrimeFaces 6.1 its working fine and validation message getting displayed. But in PrimeFaces 6.2 validation Message not displaying in dialog. I know RequestContext  is deprecated in PF 6.2. Am also tried with below code,

```
PrimeFaces primefaces = PrimeFaces.current();
primefaces.ajax().update("dialog");
primefaces.executeScript("PF('widgetVar').show();");
```

Facing same issue. I saw that message displaying and immediately its getting cleared.
But, when I remove the ajax update `primefaces.ajax().update("dialog");` It's working fine.

What is the reason for this issue?

Comment: I can only add one comment to this question... [mcve]...

Comment: "Am upgrading application from PrimeFaces 6.1 to PrimeFaces 6.2". Try upgrading to 7.0. Please note that 8.0 is around the corner, so testing with a 8.0-SNAPSHOT is also something to consider.

Comment: With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-open-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit) you can avoid to reopen your dialog